# Git hooks (bare). Как узнать имя ветки, в которую был внесен последний коммит?

Tags: linux, git, bash, githooks

Или как в хуке, на стороне сервера,  узнать название ветки, в которую происходит `push`?

Answer (score 6):

В `post-receive` на stdin хука поступают строчки с ref'ами вида `<oldref> <newref> <refname>`. Соответственно, можно поступить как-то так (bash):

```
# post-receive
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # Не самый правильный подход, т.к. там может быть и не refs/heads/master,
    # а какой-нибудь refs/tags/foo. Но если нужно просто, как в примере, отследить
    # не добавили ли что в ветку — обычно сойдет.
    branch=$(echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3)

    if [ "production" == "$branch" ]; then
        …
    fi
done
```

Вызывается это один раз на push (точнее, на происходящий во время push'а receive-pack).

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо [DevMan](http://habrahabr.ru/users/DevMan/) тут: [Git hooks (bare). Как узнать имя ветки в которую был внесен последний коммит?](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/27451/)

Решение `post-update hook`.

```
#!/bin/bash

branch=`git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $1`
echo "Pushed to branch '$branch'"
```

Спасибо drdaeman за ваш вариант. Учту if на bash.